# I need shorter dividers in my topbar (using foundation)

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation and my topbar looks the way I want it to except for one thing, I want the dividers to be shorter, and I can't get them to be any other way. Right now they are full length.

Example of my code:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
  <ul class="title-area">
    <li class="name">
    </li>
                <!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
</ul>
 <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="centered"> 
        <li> <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/">one</a> </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        <li> <a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/?page_id=22">two</a> </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
        <li> <a href="#">three</a> </li> 
            <li class="divider"></li>
        <li> <a href="#">four</a> </li> 
             <li class="divider"></li>
        <li> <a href="#">five</a> </li> 
    </ul>
 </section>
</nav>
```

The CSS from foundation looks like this:

```
$topbar-divider-border-bottom: solid 1.8px #c6b456;
$topbar-divider-border-top: solid 1.8px #c6b456;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the top-bar divider `border-right` property is taken from

line-609 of _topbar.scss

```
& > ul > .divider,
        & > ul > [role="separator"] {
          border-bottom: none;
          border-top: none;
          border-#{$opposite-direction}: $topbar-divider-border-bottom;
          clear: none;
          height: $topbar-height;
          width: 0;
        }
```

that is set from the variable `$topbar-divider-border-bottom`

If you just want to change the `border-right` with out effecting the rest of the properties you have to set it manually in the above sass.

or override using the custom css

```
.top-bar-section > ul > .divider, .top-bar-section > ul > [role="separator"] {
 border-right: solid 1px #4e4e4e;
}
```

or ovveride using sass

Answer (score 1):

Here's the actual foundation generated css

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
    .top-bar-section > ul > .divider, .top-bar-section > ul > [role="separator"] {
          border-bottom: none;
          border-top: none;
          border-right: solid 1px #4e4e4e;
          clear: none;
          height: 45px;
          width: 0; }
}
```

I guess you can override the **height** to make it shorter and add **margin-top** to make it vertically centered.